# Why is the error message not being displayed when the validation fails?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, frontend, react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form and for the life of me can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the following implementation:

**form.jsx**

```
"use client";

import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as utils from "../utils/validations.js";

const Form = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { isValid, errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      compressionLevel: 90,
    },
  });

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })}
    >
      <label htmlFor="file">File:</label>
      <input
        {...register("file", {
          required: true,
          validate: utils.validateFile,
        })}
        type="file"
        id="file"
        accept=".png, .gif, .bmp, .tiff, .webp, .jpeg"
      />

      <p>{errors.file?.message}</p>

      <input disabled={!isValid} type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

**validations.js**

```
export function validateFile(files) {
  const fileFormat = files[0]?.type.slice(6);
  return (
    ["png", "gif", "bmp", "tiff", "webp", "jpeg"].includes(fileFormat) || "error!"
  );
```

Why is the errors object not updating even though the validating function is clearly being called and behaving as intended?

Any other suggestions would be appreciated. I am entirely new to this library and would indeed appreciate any suggestion of a better way to achieve the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to do was simply add the following mode to the useForm:

```
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        watch,
        getValues,
        formState: { isValid, errors },
      } = useForm({
        mode: "onChange",
        defaultValues: {
          compressionLevel: 90,
        },
      });
```

If I am not mistaken, this makes it so that the form validates each one of its fields as soon as it is changed, instead of waiting for the submit.